# How can I beat the first mission of the final campaign with a might warrior? 

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

I got to the final campaign (finished the inferno campaign). Ii chose Kiril (inferno) to complete the final 2 campaign missions. At the moment I am at the first mission and I found myself in a impossible situation - I have to defeat the first angel to move on and take the first fort (to open the gates) but the angel seems to be a "god".

He does not have a massive army..but he has a magic ability (lightning chain) that kills most of my army - from 20 Hellounds, 75 Lilims, 60 Demented and 15 Breeders, he kills all the Hellounds, 8 Breeders, 30 Lillims and 30 Demented. I find it impossible to defeat the angel and he also starts first. How can you beat the first mission with a might warrior?

Comment: i think the first missions name is "tears such as.."cant remember the last word

Comment: I haven't gotten that far in the game, but do you have towns?  Your army seems extremely small - you may need to spend a few months increasing the size of your army.  The boss isn't going to get any more powerful.

Comment: jason berkan i cant get to any town^^ as i mentioned before i have an angel(not boss) normal unit that has a small army but deadly abilitys for a might user

Answer (score 1):

In general, imho might heroes require more of an actual army to win battles.  You might try not using all your troops.  either use tactics or give the troops to your other hero.  With a smaller army on the field you can use abilities like intimidate & earth regeneration to very shield them.  Hard to picture your battle without more details on your skill choices & details on your enemy.

If you cannot beat the minor generals you may have chosen your skills poorly or not claimed enough stat boosts during his campaign. =/